# Scraping website in which html is injected with javascript

Tags: python

I am trying to get the url and sneaker titles at https://stockx.com/sneakers.

This is my code so far:

in **main.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from utils import generate_request_header
import requests

url = "https://stockx.com/sneakers"
html = requests.get(url, headers=generate_request_header()).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print soup
```

in **utils.py**

```
def generate_request_header():
    header = BASE_REQUEST_HEADER
    header["User-Agent"] = random.choice(USER_AGENT_HEADER_LIST)
    return header
```

But whenever I `print soup`, I get the following output: https://pastebin.com/Ua6B6241. There doesn't seem to be any HTML extracted. How would I get it? Should I be using something like Selenium?

Comment: Where is the code for `BASE_REQUEST_HEADER` and `USER_AGENT_HEADER_LIST`? are they inside the functions `scope` ?

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/E19rtbZy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` doesn't seem to be able to verify the `ssl` certificates, to **temporarily** bypass this error, you can use `verify=False`, i.e.:

```
requests.get(url, headers=generate_request_header(), verify=False)
```

---

To fix it permanently, you may want to read:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the data you're looking for are at line 126 in the pastebin. I've never tried to extract the text of a script but I'm sure it could be done.

In lxml, something like:
`source_code.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]')` should return a list of all the scripts as objects.

Or to try and get straight to the "tickers":

```
[i for i in source_code.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]') if 'tickers' in i.xpath('string')]
```